# Getting 401 Unauthorized error when installing a pod

Tags: cocoapods

I'm setting up a new pod in my pod file and when I do pod install I have an error what should I doing ?

I tried this line to add the pod in my podfile :

pod 'MapboxVisionNativeAll', :podspec => 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v1/vision/ios/mapbox-vision-native-all/0.3.0.podspec?access_token='

this the error

[!] Failed to fetch podspec for `MapboxVisionNativeAll` at `https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v1/vision/ios/mapbox-vision-native-all/0.3.0.podspec?access_token=<sk.eyJ1IjoiYnJhaGltY2hlYmJpIiwiYSI6ImNqdXlhMXl6aDBmeXo0M3BpYjV6MnFib3IifQ.VinI6ER1YN2nDxXRJzaFXw>`.
 Error: 401 Unauthorized

Answer (score 9):

=> I guess, You are misplacing your .netrc.
=> The .netrc file should be in your home directory (~ on the command line, or use Go ‣ Home in Finder).

1. In terminal type: cd ~
2. touch .netrc
3. open .netrc
4. paste below to .netrc with SecretKey

   ```
   machine api.mapbox.com 
   login mapbox
   password <INSERT SecretKey>
   ```
5. Enjoy: pod install will work without error

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs if the token is invalid.

I tried accessing the link from the error and it says that the token is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Following is my working Podfile

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '11.2'
use_frameworks!

target 'PROJECT_NAME' do
    pod 'MapboxVisionNativeAll', :podspec => 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v1/vision/ios/mapbox-vision-native-all/0.3.0.podspec?access_token=sk.eyJ1IjoiZWRkeXZlcmJydWdnZW4iLCJhIjoiY2p1c3F5eGVpMDA1eTRlbzJpOXJwdDIxMCJ9.OZRITqde9clot1E8Za_OsQ'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In terminal:

1. touch .netrc
2. open .netrc
3. paste below to .netrc with SecretKey

```
    machine api.mapbox.com
    login mapbox
    password <INSERT SecretKey>
```

4. pod install

***Note*** To use your secret token, you will need to store it in a .netrc file in your **HOME** directory (not your project folder) - https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/guides/install/ (Configure your secret token)*